# Listen to Preference change from outside PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android, preferenceactivity

I'm using [wordpress-passcode-lock library](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/Android-PasscodeLock) for providing a PIN lock feature to my app.
I'm also using Google Analytics to track custom events.

I want to add a custom event for when a user sets a PIN.

If I hadn't used the above library the event could've been sent from a Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener. 
Problem is that the library provides a `PasscodePreferencesActivity` which handles the PIN preference.

So basically I'm looking for a way to bind a listener to a Preference that it's not defined in the current activity.

Is there any way to achieve this without having to fork the library and directly modifying the listener method?